# Background process doesn't work after closing the ssh

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, ssh, deployment

I'm using an SSH script for remote deployment. After push to the master branch the repository connects via SSH and calls deploy.sh which should run in the background so as not to waste the devops node's running time. Inside the script, docker restarts and pulls from the repo. I tried nohup, &, disown - but the result remains the same: the script only works correctly if it terminates within the SSH console. If we close the SSH connection, nothing happens, as if we never called the script. Why would this happen?

Comment: Have you tried using `setsid`?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same. If you run it from under Putty, it works. But if you send an SSH command, no

Comment: It sounds like the remote command(s) requires a TTY; when disowned/backgrounded, TTY-dependent operations (even if it's not something you want/need) will cause the process to pause and/or fail. Does the overall behavior change if you call `ssh -T` (using upper-`T`, disabling pseudo-terminal allocation)?

Comment: The `-T ' flag helped! Everything worked, thank you!